# encode URI of downloaded image of S3

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, amazon-s3

I have upload a image on AWS S3 server with following path :
https://dummy_momain/FeetPort/277/294/93/harwindersingh/2015-07-24/harwindersingh_2015-07-24_15:03:34:0660.jpeg

as i download it with S3 browser. it download the image and convert it into following format:
http://192.168.21.145/277/93/harwindersingh/2015-07-24/harwindersingh_2015-07-24_15%253A03%253A34%253A0660.jpeg

as i used javascript function **escape,encodeURI** and **encodeURIComponent** it convert the path into: 
http://192.168.21.145/277/93/harwindersingh/2015-07-24/harwindersingh_2015-07-24_15%3A03%3A34%3A0660.jpeg

both the strings are not mached. i need help on converting

**harwindersingh_2015-07-24_15:03:34:0660.jpeg** into **harwindersingh_2015-07-24_15%253A03%253A34%253A0660.jpeg** format.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  The `%253A` indicates that you've made an error during *upload*, with `:` > `%3A` > `%253A` revealing double urlencoding.  Your question, and the answer provided, is essentially solving the problem "how do I ensure that I can keep making this same mistake?" When in fact you should be trying to figure out why it's being uploaded wrong.

Comment: File has been uploaded using AWS SDK.. file shown in the bucket correctly but i download file with a 3rd party software.. may be that software convert it into this format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like if you do `encodeURIComponent` two times, you can achieve that. I think in the process of uploading and downloading the encoding happens two times.

```js
var string = encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('harwindersingh_2015-07-24_15:03:34:0660.jpeg'));

document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```